# com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None) on Python

Tags: python, class, win32com

I am on Win10 Enterprise (64-bit) and I want to extract some email from mailbox IBM Notes ver 9.

Below is my code to initiate the session for IBM Notes:

```py
import win32com.client
notes_session = win32com.client.Dispatch("Lotus.NotesSession")
```

Unfortunately, I got an error something like

> com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)

Could anyone assist me on how to fix this? I did some Googling that this issue might happened due to versioning of 32-64 bit something on this.

Comment: And you [already did a search](/help/how-to-ask) on `com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)`? Because I'm seeing quite a few of questions on SO just for that (although it's not immediately clear whether this is a duplicate of any of those). Please [edit] your post to cover all those questions and how they didn't help you address the problem.